# How to initialize classes after multiple classes inheritance in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

`class A` and `class B` are part of `class C`, I separate them for the **single responsibility principle**, so I inherit them in class C, they need different variables for initialization, I faced error when using `super().__init__(b=b, d=d)`

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print(f"A is init param={a}")


class B:
    def __init__(self, b, d):
        print(f"B is init param={b} {d}")


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d):
        super().__init__(a=a)
        super().__init__(b=b, d=d)


c = C(a=3, b=5, d=9)
```

I got error:

```py
super().__init__(b=5, d=9)
TypeError: A.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'
A is init param=3
```

How can I inherit both `class A` and `class B` while initialize them with different variables?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use `super()` in this case. You have to call the `__init__()` methods directly:

```py
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d):
        A.__init__(self, a=a)
        B.__init__(self, b=b, d=d)
```